# static void * const in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Is there a way of writing the following in swift?

```
static void * const SomeContext = (void*)&SomeContext;
```

I understand that static is used in structs and enums for declaring type methods. Not sure what could substitute this.

Comment: Is the code provided in a class or a struct ?

Comment: The code is provided outside of a class's interface/implementation. Mostly, I need to use it to add observers for different properties and I want to create a context in swift.